# unbind C-m from RET

Tags: emacs, elisp

In my emacs config file I have created a minor mode so that I can re-bind keys without having to rebind them separately for each major mode.

In doing so, I have re-mapped `C-m` to `kill-ring-save`. However, in default emacs `C-m` is the same as `RET`. Therefore when I have the following in my .emacs :

```
 (define-key my-minor-mode-map (kbd "C-m") 'kill-ring-save)
```

When I press the return key, `kill-ring-save` is executed

How should I go about fixing my config file so that I don't run into these problems?

I am also open to taking a different approach to creating a key binding that works in all major modes.

Edit: I am running in graphical mode

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This won't work in a non-graphical mode emacs.  When run in a terminal, <kbd>return</kbd> and <kbd>C-m</kbd> are not distinguishable.

If you're not running terminal mode emacs, just rebind `<return>` and `C-m` separately.

For example:

```
(cond (window-system  ; ensure not running in a terminal
       (local-set-key (kbd "<return>") 'newline)
       (local-set-key (kbd "C-m") 'kill-ring-save)))
```

Comment: I'm running in gui mode, but since `"C-m"` is the same as `enter` in emacs nothing i'm doing (including variations on your answer) has been working for me.

Comment: Try `C-h k <return>` to get show the key binding for return.  It should initially show `RET (translated from <return>) runs...`.  After rebinding, it should just say `<return> runs ...`.  Once `<return>` is not longer being translated to `RET`, you should be able to bind them independently.

Comment: Try starting Emacs with '-q' to make sure none of your configurations interfere. Then paste ataylor's code in the scratch-buffer and evalute it. When I do that in my GNU Emacs 23.2.1 on Ubuntu, everything works as expected (apart from the fact that `'new-line` should be `'newline`).